# MQ135 output on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

I bought an FC-22 (MQ135) gas sensor module which I plugged into my Arduino Uno. I connected it to the A0 analog port. Then created a code that reads the raw data from A0 (code below).

When I run the code on my Arduino Uno in my house I get values of about 30. If I blow over the sensor I get values until about 160. My question is now how I have to read / interpret these values.

According to the MQ135 specifications the sensor has a sesitivity for air quality, measuring benzene, alcohol and smoke.

How can I interpret the values I get? What is a good value and what isn't? Do I have to calculate something out of these values?

My code looks like this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(0);
  Serial.print(sensorValue, DEC);
  delay(100);
  if (sensorValue > 50) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: any reference for co2 calibration?

Comment: @manish As for now the only info I have is from the answer below in the datasheet of the MQ135.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/SNS-MQ135/resources/SNS-MQ135.pdf) you have to calibrate it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the datasheet. Yep, at the end of the document indeed it says to calibrate the sensor to either 100ppm NH3 or 50ppm Alcohol. Unfortunately, I haven't got the tools to create an atmosphere with these contents. Furthermore, I'd be more interested in CO2 values, even if I didn't state that in the initial question.

Comment: @Socrates Any update on CO2? I'm struggling with it. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe I haven't got any update on this yes, sorry. Please post it here, if you get it running.